# Creating audio player in java

Tags: java, audio, inputstream

I'm trying to play a simply mp3 file using java. The code I have written is:

```
public void playAudio(String fileSource) {

  try (InputStream music = new FileInputStream(fileSource)) {
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(music);

    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
  }
}
```

but when I provide the method with the file path nothing is being played. What is the code missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example can play midi, wav files, maybe some others, but not mp3, because of patent issues, but If you can use JavaFX, then you can play mp3 like this:

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(()->{});
        
        Media sound = new Media(new File("C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\Desktop\\someFile.mp3").toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        player.play();
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000); //don't exit too early
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.exit();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can use some other libraries like [Java Stream Player](https://github.com/goxr3plus/java-stream-player)

By the way, correct syntax for your initial example is:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("someFile.wav");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AudioStream as = null;
try {
    as = new AudioStream(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

Comment: Thank you, I've converted the file to a wav and its working fine with the new syntax. Can you explain why the streams are working now they have been declared outside of the try blocks? I originally enclosed them in the bracket as I thought they had to be closed?

Comment: Great! Actually I was testing your example and also got silence :-) And then i found some other example. Normally try catch syntax is: try { //  Block of code to try } catch(Exception e) { //  Block of code to handle errors } Round brackets () in your try block is for resource declaration i guess, but what's happening in your example is that application finishes fast and destroys all resources before player starts to play.

Comment: Now i found that your example works if you put Thread.sleep(10000); after player statement! Also you can put all code to one big try block, if you want, although it is only required for `new FileInputStream("someFile.wav")` and `new AudioStream(in)`